# iOS - Settings - Modal Segue to Table view controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uitableview, application-settings, segue

I would like to build a settings interface for the iOS app.

**Note** - These settings would often change so I prefer a setting interface app instead of the settings bundle

**My thoughts**

- I liked the **modal** segue to get to the settings view
- my settings view is going to be a table view
- I prefer if the table view is static (as each cell might lead to a different view)

**Problems:**

1. In **modal** view, the navigation bar doesn't seem to appear. I would need the navigation bar, so that I can create a "Save" button on it ?
2. In order to solve the above mentioned, I created a UIViewController to manage the settings view and added a navigation bar and a table view under the UIViewController's view (Using a UITableViewController to cause the navigation bar to scroll with the cells)
3. But creating a UIViewController doesn't allow me to create a table with static content

**Questions:**

1. How can the above mentioned be achieved ?
2. Is there a better way to do a settings screen ?
3. Is it better to create dynamic content tables and have different cell identifiers for different types cells (e.g. cells with slider / cells with text box etc) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using Storyboarding, this is a very easy thing to accomplish. Just add a new scene to your storyboard:
[image]

...then add a `UIBarButtonItem` to your main scene:
[image]

...then link the `UIBarButtonItem` to the scene you just added by using Control+Click to drag from the button to the scene. Choose a "modal" transition:
[image]

...then, in the new scene you've added, you can customize the table cells by using the right-hand side menu. If you choose "Custom" as the cell type, you can add switches, etc to the tableview.
[image]

From there, I'd recommend you take a look at hooking those switches up to methods, and then take a look at `NSUserDefaults` for how to store the settings and link them up to this viewController. [Here's the documentation for NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have some doubts: 1) when the settings button in the master view controller is clicked, should I segue to the Detail view controller or the Table view controller. 2)How does your (according to the screenshot) table view controller have a toolbar (on top) even before segueing ? 3) how is the detail view controller and table view controller connected ?

Comment: In question in the comments above I have mentioned toolbar but i actually meant navigation bar. When I add a navigation bar to the table view controller, the navigation bar gets pushed below the cell.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! Awesome solution !!. Sorry it took a while for me to understand. Just to summarize my understanding based on what you suggested: When the user clicks on settings button, it needs to segues (modal segue) into a new navigation controller. Then create a new table view controller which would represent the settings. Now this "settings" table view controller needs to be made the root view controller of the newly created navigation controller. So the project would contain 2 navigation controllers.

Comment: That sounds about right! You can definitely use a second navigation controller to represent the settings. You'll also need to create some methods for storing and updating the settings that the user changes, but NSUserDefaults is a great place to start for that.